# Formatting list of figures with no space on left side

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, tocloft

Basically I want this:

> Abbildungsverzeichnis
>
> Abbildung 1: somecaptiontextxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.........................................................34

Abbildung 1 is the name of the figure. It equals figure 1, figure 2 etc. Abbildungsverzeichnis means list of figures. I didn't translate it in English, because the picture at the bottom is all in German, which shows the actual state of my list of figures.

But the code I used:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newlength{\mylen}

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename\enspace} 
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}
```

produced this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution using `tocloft`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength\mylen
\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{0em}

\let\orignumberline\numberline
\let\origlistoffigures\listoffigures

\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
  \renewcommand\numberline[1]{%
    \settowidth\mylen{\figurename\enspace:##1\enspace}%
    \orignumberline{\figurename\enspace##1:\enspace\hspace{-\mylen}}\hspace{\mylen}%
  }%
  \origlistoffigures
  \let\numberline\orignumberline
}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\clearpage

\section{Test}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{this is just a caption for a test figure, we add some more text here so the caption will span several lines}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are willing to change to [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) instead of `tocloft`, here's how it's done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\titlecontents{figure}
  [0em]
  {}
  {\figurename\enspace\thecontentslabel:\enspace}
  {}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{this is just a caption for a test figure, we add some more text here so the caption will span several lines}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting LoF:

[image]

Comment: I used the second suggestion with titletoc and it works perfectly fine. Is there the possibility to add some vertical space between the elements of the list for better readability? At the moment, the elements of the figure list are too close to each other.

Comment: @NuCore Sure. Use the last optional argument to add the desired space, as in `\titlecontents{figure}
  [0em]
  {}
  {\figurename\enspace\thecontentslabel:\enspace}
  {}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\vskip10pt]`

Answer (score 1):

You would have to adjust the way [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) constructs the LoF entry by modifying the margin lengths that are set. Below is a redefinition of `\l@figure` from `tocloft` to provide you with the necessary output:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@figure}[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@lofdepth >\z@
    \vskip \cftbeforefigskip
    {%\leftskip \cftfigindent\relax
     \rightskip\z@%\rightskip \@tocrmarg
     \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent\z@%\parindent \cftfigindent\relax
    \@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima \cftfignumwidth\relax
     \let\@cftbsnum \cftfigpresnum
     \let\@cftasnum \cftfigaftersnum
     \let\@cftasnumb \cftfigaftersnumb
     \null\nobreak%\advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {\cftfigfont #1}\nobreak
     \cftfigfillnum{#2}}%
   \fi
  }
\makeatother
```

The commented parts have been changed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@figure}[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@lofdepth >\z@
    \vskip \cftbeforefigskip
    {%\leftskip \cftfigindent\relax
     \rightskip\z@%\rightskip \@tocrmarg
     \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent\z@%\parindent \cftfigindent\relax
    \@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima \cftfignumwidth\relax
     \let\@cftbsnum \cftfigpresnum
     \let\@cftasnum \cftfigaftersnum
     \let\@cftasnumb \cftfigaftersnumb
     \null\nobreak%\advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {\cftfigfont #1}\nobreak
     \cftfigfillnum{#2}}%
   \fi
  }
\makeatother

\newlength{\mylen}

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename\enspace} 
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:\enspace}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{this is just a caption for a test figure, we add some more text here so the caption will span several lines}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Keeping the `\rightskip \@tocrmarg` option leaves you with the following output:

[image]

You could also use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to redefine `\l@figure`, if needed. It won't be much cleaner.